# Model returns a Nan value

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, data-science

I was trying to build a neural network with 4 input nodes/ features and just one output feature(0/1). I wrote this code and it runs but while training the model returns NaN. I debugged too and weights and biases are fine until they go through the model.

From what I've searched so far, this could be a problem in the way I am passing the data. 
My input data is : `tensor([[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 1.5340e+00],
        [1.5000e+01, 1.0000e-01, 2.4210e+00, 3.0000e+01],
        [3.0000e+00, 2.2000e-01, 2.2000e-01, 4.5000e+01],
        ...,
        [1.0000e+00, 2.0000e-02, 2.0000e-02, 1.5000e+01],
        [6.0000e+00, 2.0000e-01, 2.0000e-01, 1.5000e+01],
        [1.7000e+01, 5.2400e-01, 5.2400e-01, 2.0000e+00]], dtype=torch.float64)`

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable
# Import tensor dataset & data loader
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
from torch import nn, optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

file = pd.read_csv('ks-projects-201801.csv')
array = np.array(file.values)
result = np.empty(len(array))
input_data = np.empty((len(array), 4))
for i in range(len(array)):
    input_data[i] = np.array([array[i][10], array[i][12]/1000, array[i][13]/1000, array[i][14]/1000])
    if array[i][9] == 'successful':
        result[i] = 1
    else:
        result[i] = 0


input_node = Variable(torch.from_numpy(input_data))
output = torch.from_numpy(result)
print(input_node)
print(output)

train_ds = TensorDataset(input_node.squeeze(), output.squeeze())

batch_size = 5
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

This is the actual model and training

```
model = nn.Linear(4, 1)
print(model.weight)
print(model.bias)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.003)

epochs = 5
model = model.double()
for e in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    for xb, yb in train_dl:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        res = model(xb)
        loss = criterion(res, yb)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
    else:
        print(f"model : {loss}")
```

This prints out model: nan for every epoch and terminates. I am very new to pytorch and I'm not sure how to handle this problem.

Comment: Can you show the values of `xb`, `yb` in the training loop?

Comment: Do you really want to print `loss` or did you intend to print `running_loss`?

Answer (score 1):

If you see NaN's in loss try gradient clipping and data normalisation. Normalising data is a must (i.e normalize input data such that mean  = 0 and variance =1)